# X11: How to disable the combined display desktop, so screens can be adressed with DISPLAY=:0.x

Tags: xorg, display

I have an ubuntu 18.04 Desktop Edition installed, to control a setup with three displays.
For this special project, it would be easier to adress the displays one by one, e.g. DISPLAY=:0.1 :0.2 and so on.
Currently I can get it only to work with specifying "--geometry" and crazy offsets.

How do I disable this multi-monitor support on Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop edition?
Is there an easy way, e.g. by deinstalling some package?

BR
Marc

Answer (score 0):

OK, just for the record. After digging around a little I found the ZaphodHeads setting ( -> /etc/X11/xorg.conf ), together with the xrandr tool enabled me to find a setting where all monitors work now.

As I have an Intel chipset in my computer this link also was of great help: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/4-intel/

Here comes the relevant part of my current /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel0"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
    Screen      0
    Option      "AccelMethod"       "sna"
    Option      "Monitor-HDMI1"     "HDMI1"
    Option      "ZaphodHeads"       "0:HDMI1"
    Option      "TearFree"  "on"
    Option      "ReprobeOutputs"    "on"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel1"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
    Screen      1
    Option      "AccelMethod"       "sna"
    Option      "Monitor-HDMI2"     "HDMI2"
    Option      "ZaphodHeads"       "1:HDMI2"
    Option      "TearFree"  "on"
    Option      "ReprobeOutputs"    "on" 
EndSection
```